# ReferenceError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined in userFunction (Autodesk's viewer)

Tags: node.js, webpack, module, es6-promise, autodesk-viewer

My app.bundle.js created by webpack is effing up:

```
/* harmony import */ var firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(10);
/* harmony import */ var firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(16);

var firebaseConfig = {
  //config options for database
}; // Initialize Firebase

var defaultProject = firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var defaultFirestore = defaultProject.firestore();
console.log("Firebase globals: ", firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default);

function userFunction(pdb) {
  console.log("Firebase globals inside function: ", firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default);
}
```

As you can see `firebase_app_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__` is defined at the top yet when loading webpage error `ReferenceError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__` is not defined pops up out of nowhere.

**Update:**
I actually found the mistake, basically I'm using **Autodesk's Forge Viewer Library** which at some point calls my function userFunction, userFunction needs firebase to process a list in one pass, sadly this function is executed in a webworker (async) which means I can't easily reference a variable outside the function's scope.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add an import for each Firebase SDK you want to use.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import ....
```

If you already have done so, you also need them to be in correct order in a react project

The correct order:

```
import './initializedFirebase'

import App from './App'
```

If you import App.jsx before initializeFirebase.js, then firebase.storage() is used before it gets initialized.

Also consider upgrading your version of Firebase which solves many issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I actually found the mistake, basically I'm using Autodesk's Forge Viewer Library which at some point calls my function userFunction, userFunction needs firebase to process a list in one pass, sadly this function is executed in a webworker (async) which means I can't easily reference a variable outside the function's scope. Thank you again for your help!